# What is the best way to add space between elements in a wrapper div with display:flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a situation I encounter frequently. I need to add spacing between elements within a wrapper div, the wrapper uses display flex and the elements are aligned using `justify-content: center`, I want to add spacing between the elements within the wrapper, however, my options are `justify-content:space-between` which isn't visually appealing since I want all my elements centered with more space from the ends. `justify-content:space-around` doesn't look good either, cause I want more space from the ends to the border of the container, and a little space between elements.
What's the best way to approach this?

```
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nums">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
style.css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nums{
    width:100px;
    margin:0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    /* padding:15px; */

}

/*
.nums div{
    margin:10px;
}

*/
```

I've tried adding padding to my wrapper div, but that doesn't seem to add any space between my elements within the wrapper div, is the only way to solve this is using `justify-content:center` to my wrapper class and adding a margin to children elements within wrapper?
or is there something I'm missing that's making padding not work?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use `gap`, as this is its purpose, to add spacing between adjacent elements:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nums {

  border: 1px solid #000;
  inline-size: fit-content;
  margin-block: 1em;
  margin-inline: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 15px;
}

.nums > div {
  background-color: hsl(35 95% 70% / 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="nums">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

References:

- [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap)